# jQuery show not executing when expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I have an APEX application with a button that is calling a javascript function.  The function is doing some screen scraping and takes a few seconds to complete. I want to display a spinner icon first to provide the sense that something is happening.  However, even though I have the spinner displaying with a jquery .show() call prior to the function call, they seem to both get executed at the same time....seconds after the button click.  It's as if the jquery .show() won't execute until the function call is complete.  How do I get the .show() to execute prior to the call to the function?  I even tried adding the .show() to the first line of the function but the result is the same.  Spinner doesn't display until after the function has completed.

Comment: You intentionally typo'd your title to get around the fact that a question with that exact name already exists. **Don't do that**. Come up with a name that actually describes your question.

Comment: can you show the code you have that reproduces this problem

Comment: You can make the icon appear before the function is called using `setTimeout`, but it won't be animated while the function runs.

Comment: I most certainly did not intentionally type that title.  Please don't accuse me of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show accepts a callback function as a parameter. See example below.

[jQuery.show() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
function buttonHandler() {
    $(".spinner").show(function() {
        // this will be executed after show has completed
    });
}
```

Comment: `show` isn't an animation function unless you pass it a duration or a callback, of course. :-) But yes, this works.

Comment: True, I've remove unclear wording from the answer

Comment: I forgot that show accepts a callback function.  Thanks for the tip, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the .show() to execute prior to the call to the function?

You call `.show`, then yield back to the browser for a tiny bit of time, before calling the function, like this:

```
function buttonHandler() {
    $("...").show();
    setTimeout(theFunction, 0);
}
```

You'll have to experiment with your target browsers to determine whether you need a value larger than `0`. The value is in milliseconds, so anything up to 50 or so will be largely-unnoticable to a human.

By not calling the function until after you've yielded back to the browser, you give the browser a chance to update the display.

Note that the spinner may not be animated while the function is tying things up, it depends on the browser. You may prefer to show something static but dynamic-looking (the way "go faster" stripes are) to avoid inconsistency between browsers.

Live example using 50ms:

```js
$("#the-button").on("click", buttonHandler);
function buttonHandler() {
  $("#spinner").show();
  $("#done").hide();
  setTimeout(theFunction, 50);
}
function theFunction() {
  var target = Date.now() + 1000;
  while (Date.now() < target) {
    // Do nothing, we're just simulating a busy function
  }
  $("#spinner").hide();
  $("#done").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="Click me">
<div id="spinner" style="display:none">We're doing it, one sec!</div>
<div id="done" style="display:none">Function is done now</div>
```

Comment: I've always found this to be specific to Chrome for some reason.

Comment: @Andy: `0` works in recent IE, too. Firefox wants longer, `50` works for the above (on my system).